# How to model walkable houses for Unity

Tags: unity, blender

I created a house in blender which is a big cube with the upper face intended and pulled down back to the ground. The floors are other boxes and windows and doors are cut out using a boolean modifier. The problem is that the character controller from the Unity standard assets seems to get stuck between the floors and the walls. I have seen that counter strike maps are mostly not made out of cubes but a lot of planes put together. Is that the proper way to model walkable buildings?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of what you have? I am finding your description difficult to imagine.

Comment: Imagine being in a room walking right next to the wall. When I walk straight into the wall sometimes when I want to walk away from it I can only walk along the wall for a short amount of time. Not always and on different spots. It seems like the other axis is blocked. I can make a video if that helps, an image won't explain it.

Comment: And your collision mesh matches your visual mesh exactly, I presume?

Comment: The house yes, the player is a capsule

Comment: That's it? No more ideas left?